# How can I consume satellite assemblies declaratively in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, satellite-assembly

This is it, I've been learning about satellite assemblies, and I think I already understood how to create them and how to use them **in code with the ResourceManager**

The problem is that I would like to consume a satellite assmebly via the page's markup (declaratively) but I have not found a way to do it.

Any thoughts?

My goal is to be able to use them something like this:

```
<asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:[external assembly][resources file name], [resource key] %>">

</asp:Localize>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement your own Custom [ResourceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx) where you would build out your methods that use those assemblies.